# How a Teenage student should behave?

Tags: scripture, vedas, life, manu-smriti

Is there any specific quote or reference in Hindu scripture related to the behavior and lifestyle of young Lerner.

I understand that Sanatan Dharma is never about to-do and don't list but I believe there must be a fine guide of required attributes.

Comment: Hinduism most definitely has a "to do and don't do" list.

Comment: Seems to me this question is asking for the qualities of a good brahmacárya. Voting to leave open

Comment: Yes , also particular ethics and behaviour to follow.

Comment: Teenage is precious time in life, I personally think no restrictions and proper guidance from elders help them to reach higher level in their future. If you are a teenager Focus on self-compassion, avoid comparison, capitalize on specific skills and help others..

Answer (score 3):

There are 60 odd in Manusmriti that prescribe behavior for students starting from [2.175](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199651.html) . Not only do they include behavior and lifestyle, but also to-do and not-to-do list